# Why am i getting TemplateDoesNotExist at /rapport/?

Tags: python, django, templates

i would like to view my home page/ index view but i keep getting this error, what do i need to do to get rid of this error message below? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the error message:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rapport/
rapport/index.html, rapport/description_list.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rapport/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
rapport/index.html, rapport/description_list.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\sbyeg\anaconda3\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  C:\Users\sbyeg\anaconda3\envs\new_env\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\django_projects\\rship',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sbyeg\\anaconda3\\envs\\new_env\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Mon, 07 Nov 2022 12:32:56 +0300
```

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Description

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'rapport/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'description_list'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five keyed entries"""
        return Description.objects.order_by('-event_date')[:5]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

**index.html template**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Description List</h1>
  <ul>
     {% if description_list %} 
    {% for description in description_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ description.get_absolute_url }}">{{ description.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
      
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no entries in the repository.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse # Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns
import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Description(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description_text = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text='Enter a brief description of your entry' )
    reminder_date = models.DateTimeField('date to be reminded')
    event_date = models.DateTimeField('date of event')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title #, #self.reminder_date, self.event_date
    
    def is_upcoming(self):
        return self.event_date <= timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the URL to access a detail record of this description."""
        return reverse('description-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['event_date']
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

directory path to templates:
[image: my templates directory]

if the information is insufficient, contact me to know what you need to help in resolving this error message.

Here is **my projects' urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #Use include() to add paths from the rapport application
    path('rapport/', include('rapport.urls')),
    #Add URL maps to redirect the base URL to our application
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='rapport/', permanent=True))
    
]
```

Here's a link to the github repo:
https://github.com/Sam25498/Django-Projects/

Comment: Can you also share your project's urls.py? And also maintain proper gap in `DIRS` so `[BASE_DIR / "templates"]`

Comment: @SunderamDubey I just added the project's urls.py .

Comment: @SunderamDubey The proper spacing didn't work.

Comment: At last, can you share the GitHub repo if possible?

Comment: @SunderamDubey the link to the github repo as been added to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"],
```

To this:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'rapport','templates')],
```

Note: your templates folder must be inside in your project or app.

Comment: Dear Manoj, it is not right it is same, `BASE_DIR` already have os.path.join at above the file of settings.py by resolving parent.parent.

Comment: @SunderamDubey It is also correct,. why i added rapport in dirs becuase, In templates directory, there is a folder called rapport, inside this folder, all templates are available so that's why i have added rapport inside DIR

Comment: It's not necessary when someone made templates folder inside the app.

Comment: @SunderamDubey i know that but when we always get template does not exit even our settings are correct so that time we can try this way

Comment: Anyway, wait for the OP reply.